# Hazelcast MapStore and transaction

Tags: transactions, hazelcast

Hazelcast' documentation says that MapStore/QueueStore does not participate in the transaction.
I was wondering, how do you generally approach the problem? Do you acknowledge that something potentially bad may happen during persisting the value in the commit phase and decide to ignore it, or do you implement a solution for that particular problem?

I understand the risks behind the problem itself, just trying to understand what options are there to mitigate it.

Also, if anyone has actually considered it to be of a big priority, it would be perfect if you could share some code around, just as an example.

Thanks,
Konrad

Answer (score 2):

According to the javaDoc of [TransactionalMap](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/blob/master/hazelcast/src/main/java/com/hazelcast/core/TransactionalMap.java)

> If you need to have an XATransaction spanning Hazelcast operations and one more other XAResources (such as a database), you should not use MapStore. Instead, enlist both resources in a transaction

This is an example snippet from that javaDoc that can give you some idea to implement the desired solution.

```
HazelcastInstanceclient=HazelcastClient.newHazelcastClient();

UserTransactionManagertm=newUserTransactionManager();
tm.setTransactionTimeout(60);
tm.begin();


HazelcastXAResourcexaResource=client.getXAResource();
Transactiontransaction=tm.getTransaction();
transaction.enlistResource(xaResource);

//you can enlist more resources here like a database XAResource
try{
TransactionContextcontext=xaResource.getTransactionContext()
TransactionalMapmap=context.getMap("map");
map.put("key","value");
final TransactionalQueue queue=context.getQueue("queue");
queue.offer("item");

//you can do other resource operations like store/delete to a database

transaction.delistResource(xaResource,XAResource.TMSUCCESS);
tm.commit();
}catch(Throwablet){
t.printStackTrace();
transaction.delistResource(xaResource,XAResource.TMFAIL);
tm.rollback();
}
```